# HTTP status 410 entire domain using classic ASP

Tags: redirect, asp-classic, wildcard, status

Two domains are pointing at my IIS 7.5 server. One domain serves a site, the other I would like to return a 410 Gone status for ANY URL that references that domain. Because I have not added a DNS entry for the 410 domain, the server returns the IIS default site. I added the following to the default.asp file on the default site:

```
<%
if instr(lcase(Request.ServerVariables("SERVER_NAME")),"legacy.somedomain.com") then
    response.Status="410 Gone"
    response.Write(response.Status)
    response.End
end if
%>
```

This works correctly is someone visits http://legacy.somedomain.com however it fails if someone visits http://legacy.somedomain.com/somepage/, a sub page URL: of the domain. I thought the above script would have wildcarded the request. Can it be modified to catch the domain and all sub page occurrences?

At present, if a user visits legacy.somedomain.com/somepage/ the system 404 page is displayed.

Comment: Set up a custom 404 page with that code.  http://www.orcsweb.com/blog/jamie-furr/how-to-create-custom-error-pages-in-iis-7-5-with-asp-net/

Comment: I have actually done that already and the sub pages are now returning a 410 status. I was hoping however that I would not have to do this for the IIS default site and 410 a 404 page server-wide. Another option I considered was creating a DNS entry and hosting space for this domain... setting up a custom 404 pages and implementing this same programming. As such, the default site is unaffected.

Comment: Another option would be to do the 410 in a Global.asa file for the site.

Comment: I would use URL Rewrite. Much cleaner than custom 404 pages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a Global.asa file in the web directory with the following code

```
<script language="vbscript" runat="server">

sub Session_OnStart
    Session("started")=now()
end sub

sub Session_OnStart
    if instr(lcase(Request.ServerVariables("SERVER_NAME")),"legacy.somedomain.com") then
        response.Status="410 Gone"
        response.Write(response.Status)
        response.End
    end if    
end sub

</script>
```

However you might actually be better of doing a permanent redirect rather than a Gone.